# Como pegar o mês e o ano atual no SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como consigo imprimir na tela o mês e o ano atual no sql ? Preciso que o mês saia em extenso.
Estou utilizando a query abaixo.

```sql
select GETDATE() from DUAL
```

Atualmente ele está sendo impresso da seguinte forma.

2018-08-21 10:34:03.253

Eu preciso que seja impresso da forma abaixo:

Agosto - 2018

Comment: Para já o que encontrei sobre o GETDATE() foi este link: http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_SELECT-Formatting_Date_Time.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o [DATENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174395(v=sql.120).aspx). Veja um  [exemplo](http://rextester.com/HOFLJO74916)

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, GetDate())   + ' de ' +  DATENAME(year, GetDate())
```

> Nota: DATENAME aplica-se a: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 até a versão atual), Banco de
>   dados SQL do Windows Azure (versão inicial até a versão atual). 
>   Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174395(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Datename é afetado pela configuração do sql, se estiver em.inglês, os nomes virão em inglês

Answer (score 5):

Tente assim:

```
    select 
    case month(getdate())
        when  1 then 'Janeiro'
        when  2 then 'Fevereiro'
        when  3 then 'Março'
        when  4 then 'Abril'
        when  5 then 'Maio'
        when  6 then 'Junho'
        when  7 then 'Julho'
        when  8 then 'Agosto'
        when  9 then 'Setembro'
        when 10 then 'Outubro'
        when 11 then 'Novembro'
        when 12 then 'Dezembro'
    end + ' - ' + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4))
 As MesAno
```

Answer (score 2):

Script para retornar uma data por extenso.

```
SET LANGUAGE Português

SELECT DATENAME(weekday, GetDate()) + ', '   +
       DATENAME(day, GetDate())     + ' de ' +
       DATENAME(month, GetDate())   + ' de ' +
       DATENAME(year, GetDate())
```

Lembrar de utilizar o `SET LANGUAGE` para retornar a data no idioma desejado, para verificar o idioma padrão de sua sessão execute `DBCC UserOptions`

Para visualizar qual é o nome dos idiomas existentes no SQL verifique na coluna name da tabela sysLanguages.

```
select * from master.dbo.syslanguages
```

Obs.: Evite usar `SET LANGUAGE` dentro de procedures pois isso irá causar RECOMPILE.

Comment: As aspas que você utilizou no exemplo está invalidando sua sintaxe.

Answer (score -2):

```
   select convert(char(02),(getdate()),101)
```

Answer (score -4):

YEAR(GETDATE())
MONTH(GETDATE())